# Why isn't my "bountiful" question appearing on the featured page?

Tags: support, bug

I started a bounty on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33692322/how-can-a-universal-windows-app-have-multiple-independent-windows-like-microsof)  . According to [What is a bounty?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) it's supposed to be featured [on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured)  . It's not. Why?

It's been over 15 minutes so I don't think it's caching.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It did.

It's on the last page, as bounties are sorted by oldest to newest, to allow questions with older bounties more visibility before they expire.

Flip over to the last result on the 8th page to see your bounty.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that. (Can't accept yet.)